# What is the proper description of an electron?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, electrons, dirac-equation, wave-particle-duality

Is it described by a trajectory with a spin $x^\mu(\tau)$, $S^\mu(\tau)$ OR a Grassmann-valued spinor field (i.e. the Dirac field a la path integral QFT) $\psi_a(x^\mu)$? If so, how are these two descriptions compatible? What is the field configuration for a given trajectory or visa versa?

Notably, I know both the Dirac field and the trajectory are meant to be classical objects so the usual particle-wave duality that comes out of quantizing can't play a role here.

Comment: Quantum particles can’t have a trajectory. A trajectory implies that the position and momentum at each instant are known exactly, which violates the Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle..

Comment: Hi @Aakash Lakshmanan. Is this question inspired by a reference? Which page?

Comment: @Ghoster I am speaking classically here

Answer (score 4):

There are many equivalent ways, within QFT, of specifying how to describe an electron.  A Grassmann-valued spinor field in the path integral is correct.  Describing the electron as a trajectory in spacetime with spin would only be correct classically.  You say in one of your comments above that you are speaking classically here, so in that case a trajectory in spacetime would be the appropriate way to describe it.

You say that the Dirac field is considered a classical object.  This is only true in the very trivial sense that any wave function of a single particle can technically be considered a classical object because its configuration space is the same as ordinary space, and so it can be viewed as an ordinary classical field on spacetime.  But there's not much value in treating it as classical in any other sense; you can't use classical electrodynamics with it, for instance.

Comment: Then how is it that we can couple the classical field $A^\mu$ with it in the QED Lagrangian? How can we put quantum objects in the Lagrangian itself? Does this not mean that we are considering superpositions of superpositions?

Comment: Aakash:  If you are interested in what objects we put in the Lagrangian in the path integral formulation, which it sounds like you are, then the answer is that for bosons we always put the classical fields in and for fermions we put Grassmann-valued fields in.  The Grassmann-valued fields are not classical fields though in any normal sense of the word "classical".

Comment: So yes, Dirac fields can be combined with classical $A^\mu$ fields in the Lagrangian of a path integral formulation.  When I said that you can't use classical electrodynamics with the Dirac field, I meant that if you are going to view the Dirac field as the wave function of an electron, then you can't combine that wave function with a classical electrodynamic field (i.e., you would have to modify that Dirac field using the appropriate quantum mechanical $A^\mu$ operator).